# Exibir índices de array cujos elementos sejam maiores que a média dos mesmos

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Tenho um array, e quero que exiba as posições numéricas dos elementos que sejam maiores que a média dos mesmos:

```js
//2 - Solicite 5 números. Exiba os que estão acima da média.
var  num, media=0;
var arrNum = [];
for(cont=0; cont < 5; cont++)
{ 
  num= parseInt(prompt("Digite um numero qualquer:"));
  arrNum[cont] = num;
  media += num/5;
}

// percorendo o vetor para achar as posições que sao maiores que a media
for(cont=0; cont < 5; cont++)
{
  // como eu pego dentro do vetor as maiores posições em relação a media?
  // Preciso armazenar em outra variavel o vetor para exibi- os valores que sao maiores que media?
  if(arrNum[cont] > media){
     arrNum[cont];
  }
}
 // mostrar o resultado final, os valores do vetor que são maiores que media!
 document.write(arrNum[cont]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ir imprimindo as posições conforme itera sobre elas, ou guardar as posições em outro array e imprimi-lo no final:

```js
// Solicitar 5 números e calcular a média
let soma = 0;
let arrNum = [];
for (let cont = 0; cont < 5; cont++) { 
    let num = parseInt(prompt("Digite um numero qualquer:"));
    arrNum.push(num);
    soma += num;
}
let media = soma / arrNum.length;

// imprimir as posições conforme são encontradas
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (arrNum[i] > media) {
    document.write('<br>posição: ' + i);
  }
}

// ou, guardar as posições em outro array e só imprimir no final
let posicoes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (arrNum[i] > media) {
    posicoes.push(i);
  }
}
document.write('<br>posições: ' + posicoes);
```

---

Outra opção (que eu particularmente acho menos legível e desnecessariamente complicada para um caso como esse, mas tem quem prefira assim) é usar [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (que gera um array com as posições):

```js
// Solicitar 5 números e calcular a média
let soma = 0;
let arrNum = [];
for (let cont = 0; cont < 5; cont++) { 
    let num = parseInt(prompt("Digite um numero qualquer:"));
    arrNum.push(num);
    soma += num;
}
let media = soma / arrNum.length;

let posicoes = arrNum.reduce(function(acc, num, index) {
  if (num > media) {
    acc.push(index);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

document.write('<br>posições: ' + posicoes);
```

---

E claro, você também pode usar [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) para percorrer os elementos (nesse caso é equivalente à primeira opção acima: imprimir as posições conforme são encontradas):

```js
// Solicitar 5 números e calcular a média
let soma = 0;
let arrNum = [];
for (let cont = 0; cont < 5; cont++) { 
    let num = parseInt(prompt("Digite um numero qualquer:"));
    arrNum.push(num);
    soma += num;
}
let media = soma / arrNum.length;

arrNum.forEach(function(num, index) {
  if (num > media) {
    document.write('<br>posição: ' + index);
  }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos por ajudarem!

Comment: @MarcelRobertoPiesigilli Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado  útil.